# Animal-sniffer maven plugin: How to convert signatures into signature artifact?

Tags: maven, animal-sniffer

I'm trying [Animal Sniffer](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/).

I've created the `.signature` files.
But to run the `check`, I need a "signature artifact".

```
<signature>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
    <artifactId>java15</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</signature>
```

This is for JDK. I need one for my project's modules.

Without it, the plugin complains:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.9:check (default-cli) on project ....
The parameters 'signature' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.9:check are missing or invalid.
```

How should I create it?

Subquestion: Can I have aggregated file for all modules of a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I simply need to "install" the `.signature` file. I.e. get it to the repo. Somehow. It doesn't appear automatically when running `build` goal.